# Optimal representation of expressions in F#

Tags: f#, expression-trees, visitor-pattern, discriminated-union

I'm working on a library to generate SQL from LINQ expressions (basically a modified subset of LINQ-to-SQL). I'm using discriminated unions to model the SQL expressions, but have encountered some (perceived?) limitations. I want to do something like the following (note the last line):

```
type SqlSourceExpression =
    | Table of string
    | Join of JoinType * SqlSourceExpression * SqlSourceExpression * SqlExpression //ie, left, right, predicate

and SqlExpression =
    | Source of SqlSourceExpression
    | OrderBy of SqlExpression * SortDirection
    | Select of SqlSourceExpression * SqlExpression * OrderBy list //can't do this
```

I could do the following:

```
type SqlOrderByExpression = SqlExpression * SortDirection
```

...and change the last two lines to:

```
    | OrderBy of SqlOrderByExpression
    | Select of SqlSourceExpression * SqlExpression * SqlOrderByExpression list
```

But that appears to have two problems:

1. SqlOrderByExpression is not a SqlExpression. This makes it hard to use the visitor pattern (maybe herein lies the problem?). Which means when traversing a Select expression I can't iterate over the list of order by expressions passing each one to Visit(expr:SqlExpression).
2. SqlOrderByExpression is merely a type alias for a tuple, so no type information is preserved. That hurts readability IMO.

Is there a better way to model this? I tried the inheritance route, but I think DUs are MUCH easier to work with (barring the noted difficulty).

Comment: I don't know if it'll be helpful, but a useful model of simple statements is available here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lexing_and_Parsing#Step_1:_Define_the_Abstract_Syntax_Tree

Comment: @Juliet - Thanks. This article has some helpful bits.

Answer (score 1):

As you work with FP technique (DU), as you don't need to remember OOP patterns, just use high-order functions (fold, map, zippers, etc).

In case you just want to specific view for your matching code, there is active patterns:

```
let (|OrderByTerm|OrderByList|_|)= function
  |OrderBy x -> Some (OrderByTerm x)
  |Select (_,_,xs) -> Some (OrderByList xs)
  |_ -> None
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `SqlExpression`, as a discriminated union, has cases for `OrderBy` and `Select`. What's allowed to go inside an `OrderBy`?

I think discriminated unions are making this more difficult than it needs to be. I think `SqlSourceExpression`, `SqlOrderByExpression` and `SqlSelectExpression` can be different types. You can make them records if you're worried about tuples being difficult to read (this is what I'd do in your situation).

I think an `SqlExpression` discriminated union will come in useful when you start to represent expression trees like `(1 + SUM(ISNULL(Value1, Value2))) / COUNT(*)`, where the syntax is more flexible.

Comment: OrderBys are actually pretty expressive. If you wanted to, you could write `order by case when table.col = value then 1 else 0 end DESC`, or even sub-selects. But in any case, I completely agree: unless there's a business requirement to handle every edge case, the OP's data model is too heavyweight for his purposes.

Comment: Good point: SqlOrderByExpression will contain an SqlExpression, but it won't be an SqlExpression in its own right.

Comment: @Juliet - Aside from the possibility of this model being too 'heavyweight' would you model these expressions similarly?

Comment: @Daniel: no I wouldn't. The definition of `SqlExpression` doesn't look correct, because <code>let x= OrderBy(Source(Table "Users"), ASC)</code> is valid F# but probably doesn't map to a valid SQL expression. Instead of trying to create a comprehensive SQL model, I'd start really small: pick a very tiny subset of SQL (i.e. no subqueries, ORDER BY clauses limited to a column name and direction, no derived tables, etc), then build your model from there. Once you can represent a limited subset of SQL, it will be easier to build up from there.